# How to draw the following set?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

Given $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$

We get the following:
$$S_1 = [-1, 1] \times [-1, 1], \:
S_2 = \{ \epsilon \in S_1 : || (\epsilon_1, 3)||\leq 5\epsilon_2 \}, \text{and }S_3 = \{ \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 1-3\epsilon_1t + \epsilon_2 t^2 \geq 0\text{ for all }0 \leq t \leq 1\}$$

How can I draw these sets? I do not know how to solve it with the epsilons and t.  Does somebody have a hint to tackle such a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be afraid of the epsilons. You can write $S_2$ as well in the form
$$S_2:=\big\{(x,y)\in S_1\bigm|\|(x,3)\|\leq 5y\bigr\}\ ,$$
and similarly
$$S_3:=\bigl\{(x,y)\in{\mathbb R}^2\bigm|1-3x t+yt^2\geq0\ (0\leq t\leq1)\bigr\}\ .$$
The $t$ here is an auxiliary variable needed to describe the intended condition on $(x,y)$.

This is a very nice problem. Be aware that there is more work involved as for a standard exercise. But you can learn a lot from it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I appreciate it. Am I correct then that I can rewrite $S_2$ as follows: $$y \geq 0.2 \sqrt{x^2 + 9} \text{ as }||(x,y)|| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

Comment: @mathguy69: You should only consider points $(x,y)\in S_1$ satisfying this inequality.